# Why does binding take so long in WP7? I can see it happening

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding

I am populating a list `searchResults` in the `Loaded` event of a page.

If this loading takes 50ms, then when I load the page by navigating back to it, I will see the previous `searchResults` for a fraction of second before the binding completes.

a) In what event can I bind controls before the page becomes visible? (The page is being navigated back to, so the constructor is not called again.)

b) Is there any way to force a binding to happen in the Loaded event code?  I notice that `list1.ItemSource=x` bindings seem to be done after the event function falls out of scope.  As if they are done in OnIdle.

More details on b)

If I run the following code:

```
(ItemsControl) lstSearchResults.ItemSource = searchResults;
int iCount = lstSearchResults.Items.Count
```

`iCount` will be zero whether there are items in the `searchResults` or not.

Is there a way to bind `lstSearchResults` to `searchResults` that populates straight away?

Answer (score 1):

1) Associate your DataContext to your viewModel and Bind the list on the UI itself using `ItemsSource={Binding searchResults}"`

2) On the Loaded event do `lstSearchResults.ItemSource = searchResults;`

Note that it is recommended that if your list is dynamic to have the lis as `ObservableCollection`

If searchResults are variable height items it may take time for the UI binding depending upon the `ItemTemplate`. To tackle that problem one should use Virtualizing StackPanel which is already a part of ListBox Control. Hence it is highly unlikely the problem to arise in your case if you are already using a listbox. For further detailed information you may go through this [resource](http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/Improving-ListBox-Performance-in-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-7-Data-Virtualization.aspx). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. OnNavigatedTo event is being called, you can try doing your work there
2. I am not completely sure what you mean but if you already did the binding between an observable collection and a listbox, then the changes you make to the observable collection will reflect in the listbox.

Comment: (1|a) Yes, that works!  Thanks!  I have added more details to (2|b)